# Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset in Spring Batch for Async

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE and Spring Batch example. I've 3 batch Jobs which runs in sequence. In 3rd Job I've used `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter`. When this batch job executes, it gives below error all the time.

How can we fix this issue?

> HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@538a3107 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class CountryBatchConfig {
    .......

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="oracleDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> EmployeeReader() throws Exception {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setSql(SELECT_Employee_SQL);

        reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> EmployeeProcessor() {
        return new EmployeeProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception{
        AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(EmployeeProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        asyncItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeWriter EmployeeWriter() {
        return new EmployeeWriter();
    }


    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemWriter() throws Exception{
        AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(EmployeeWriter());
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;  
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT XXXXXXXX]; IO Error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:763) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:844) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.SubdivisionDao.getSubDivisionByCountryId(SubdivisionDao.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.processor.EmployeeProcessor.process(EmployeeProcessor.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.processor.EmployeeProcessor.process(EmployeeProcessor.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor$1.call(AsyncItemProcessor.java:102) ~[spring-batch-integration-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1031) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3590) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1008) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:972) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:572) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:426) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:390) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1022) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

DBConfig

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="oracleDS")
    @Primary
    public DataSource batchDataSource(){          
           return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                    .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                    .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                    .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                    .build();          
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing all these issues ? Can you please reply ?

Comment: How long are these transactions taking?  This kind of error is common when you have transactions lasting too long and a firewall is cutting off the persistent connection...

Comment: @MichaelMinella - Thanks, Actually its not taking much time, Async code working fine, but for some run, I'm getting above error. Its intermittent issue. Is there any way to fixed it ?